# every time I add element to the GridView this happen in the end of it ,I can putting the height for the container by my self but its not functional

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

> **this code is working but as i said in the last 2 element of the grid view function it will cut them off if i add height  by my self to the
> container it will fix it but this solve won work if i add more element
> to the grid view function**

[enter image description here][1]

```
class _sofyappState extends State<sofyapp> {
  Color b = Colors.black;
  Color w = Colors.white;
  Color r = Colors.red;
  Color bl = Colors.blue;
  Color br = Colors.brown;

  Widget info(String text, Color color) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [color.withOpacity(0.6), color,],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.indigoAccent.withOpacity(0.9),
          spreadRadius: 0.1,
          blurRadius: 6,
          offset: Offset(0, 5), // changes position of shadow
        ),],
      ),
      child: Text("$text"),
    );
  }
  Widget foodtypesections(){
    return null;//the GridView ;

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("sofy"),
      ),
      drawer:Drawer(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          color: Color(0xffD7BDE2),

          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 10,width: 10,),
              Container(width: 100, height: 20,child: Text("Day 1",textAlign: TextAlign.center,)),
              Stack(
                  children:[
                    Container(

                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [Colors.pink,Colors.red,Colors.indigoAccent],
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
                      ),),
                    Container(
                      width: double.maxFinite,

                      color: r,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,10,10,10),
                        child: GridView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: 6,
                          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                            return info("text", Colors.indigoAccent);
                          },
                          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                            maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                            childAspectRatio: 2.1 / 2,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),  // gridview function
                  ]
              ),
              Container(width: 100, height: 20,child: Text("Day 2",textAlign: *TextAlign.center,)),*
              Stack(
                  children:[
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                      width: 350,
                      height: 340,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [Colors.pink,Colors.red,Colors.indigoAccent],
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
                      ),),
                    Container(height: 350,width: 470,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,10,10,10),
                        child: GridView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: 4,
                          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                            return info("text", Colors.indigoAccent);
                          },
                          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                            maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                            childAspectRatio: 2.1 / 2,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),  function
                  ]
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmAxf.jpg
```

here is the image for the error i mention
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmAxf.jpg

Answer (score 0):

by just putting padding inside the gridview it can work fine like this code

```
child: GridView.builder(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5,10,5,10),// the fix part
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: 6,
                          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                            return info("text", Colors.indigoAccent);
                          },
                          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                            maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                            childAspectRatio: 2.1 / 2,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                          ),
```

),